# How can I change date string from this format '2017-05-20' to 'May 20 2017 12:00AM' in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Looking for a SQL query in Redshift to change date format.

I have a column which needs to change to the new format and insert in another table in 'May 20 2017 12:00AM' format. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the format of the source column and the target column? Are they dates, timestamps or strings?

Comment: Please accept the answer below if it helps you get what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt we have a function in Redshift that does exactly what you need, but a workaround is:

```
select concat(concat(to_char(cast('2017-05-20' as date),'mon dd yyyy'),' '),'12:00AM');
```